# Why the $\zeta$ letter is like this?

Tags: soft-question

How to write the sixth letter of the Greek alphabet $\zeta$ by hand?

I cannot do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Print out a page full of printed $\zeta$ letters, and practice practice and practice.

Comment: http://www.foundalis.com/lan/hw/grkhandw.htm

Comment: @AlexNelson The zeta there is not the one used primarily in math in my experience.  It's hardly recognizable to me as a zeta, in fact.

Comment: @Goos, the difference is really negligible. Once you get *one* method of writing a zeta, it's not terribly difficult to deform the orthography into the one you desire. But *starting* with *some* zeta, I found, has been the hard part (for me anyways).

Comment: To the down voters and closers, is this question really on such as a different level as that of ["Starting sentences with mathematical symbols"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694968/starting-sentences-with-mathematical-symbols)?

Comment: @GitGud I don't see how you could possibly see a similarity between the two.

Comment: @MichaelT Neither are about actual mathematics. Both are about typography. The question I linked has the added advantage that it is about mathematical communication, but that isn't, in my opinion, reason enough to justify the disparity on the level of which these questions were received.

Comment: Wait till you get to $\xi$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many people write it as this "ζ". With the flat top, it is easier to write over and over again.